# Is there an alternative for textFieldLeader in SwiftUI's SecureField?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

As the title says, I'm trying to add some leading padding if the user provides a symbol for the icon. This works just fine in the `TextField` `View` but a `SecureField` doesn't have this as an option. Is there an alternative that I'm missing?

```swift
struct PasswordInputView: View {
    
    @Binding var password: String
    let placeholder: String
    let sfSymbol: String?
    
    var body: some View {
        
        SecureField(placeholder, text: $password)
            .frame(maxWidth: .infinity,
                   minHeight: 44)
            .padding(.leading, sfSymbol == nil ? textFieldLeader / 2 : textFieldLeader) <---- ERROR: Cannot find textFieldLeader
            .background(
            
                ZStack {
                    if let systemName = sfSymbol {
                        Image(systemName: systemName)
                            .font(.system(size: 16, weight: .semibold))
                            .padding(.leading, 5)
                            .foregroundColor(Color.gray.opacity(0.5))
                    }
                    
                    RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 10, style: .continuous)
                        .stroke(Color.gray.opacity(0.25))
                }
                
            )
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you sure `textFieldLeader` exists? I can't find it in [the docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/textfield). I get an error when I try to run this code with a `TextField`, the same as you get above. Could you give an example of using this with a `TextField`?

Comment: Hey @MrDeveloper, here is how I'm using it in TextField:

TextField(placeholder, text: $text)
            .frame(maxWidth: .infinity,
                   minHeight: 44)
            .padding(.leading, sfSymbol == nil ? textFieldLeader / 2 : textFieldLeader)
            .keyboardType(keyboardType)